# WooCommerce "Export products to a CSV file" function produces empty csv file

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, export-to-csv

Apologies if this has been answered elsewhere, but I am unable to find a solution anywhere after hours of searching.

I am trying to export around 80 WooCommerce products to CSV using WooCommerce's built-in "Export products to a CSV file" option (as described here: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/product-csv-importer-exporter/), but when saving using Chrome's Free Download Manager, it produces an empty file after a few hours (see screenshot below).

[image]

Alternatively, if I try and save it directly, bypassing the download manager, it produces a file called "edit.htm" which contains the html source of the "Export products to a CSV file" page of the WordPress dashboard, which is not particularly helpful.

I have tried disabling all plugins and changed the theme to WooCommerce Storefront as suggested by their support, but nothing helps.

I have encountered this issue on multiple sites and hosts, even on clean WP installs.

A simple export to csv should be straightforward, so this would seem to be a serious bug that WooCommerce is unwilling to acknowledge, or there is something I am doing wrong.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue? I am facing the same @Rudebaker

Comment: I never did find a solution. I ended up having to use the WooCommerce Product CSV Import Suite plugin, which works well and also allows export/import of variable products.

Answer (score 1):

For our case, WP-Stateless plugin causes the export to render empty rows in the CSV file. So the simplest solution was to disable the plugin before exporting, and then re-enable the plugin again.

Comment: How were you able to determine it was that plugin?

Answer (score 0):

The default WooCommerce Export button works for me - whether I do all fields or just some selected fields.  Problem is it gets products whether long ago sold or currently in inventory, so I'm writing my own plugin.
Hopefully you've resolved your issue by now without needing an extra plugin.

Answer (score 0):

- In my case it was the disk quota exceed on my hosting account, so no new files could be created on the server. The export function apparently creates a temporary file on the server to be downloaded, so it can not write it.
- Another scenario that could happen, is messed up permissions on the directories which deprives woocommerce from the write permissions to the temp directories.